# Pressing anywhere on the screen has the effect of the button press

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, button

[image: there is the button at the bottom]My app has a button that displays a new word in a textView and a new hint in an editText when pressed. Although when the user taps anywhere on the screen it has the same effect as the button has, which could obviously lead to a user misclikcing and ruining the experience. Could anyone recommend anything please. Here is the java for the button :

```
public void nextWord(View view) { //nextWord is the onclick of the button


        Button nextButton = findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
        Button showTextButton = findViewById(R.id.showTextButton);
        TextView wordTextView = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView);
        EditText editTextView = findViewById(R.id.enterEditText);
        ImageView logoImageView = findViewById(R.id.logoImageView);
        TextView wordTextView1 = findViewById(R.id.wordTextView1);


                i++;



        String displayHint;
        String displayText;

        displayText = enterWord() + chooseArray();
        displayHint = chooseArray();

        wordTextView.setText(displayText);
        editTextView.setHint(displayHint);
        wordTextView1.setText(displayText) ;

        if (i == 1) {

            wordTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            logoImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            wordTextView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


            //     wordTextView.setText(enterWord() + initial(0));
            //   editTextView.setHint(initial(0));


        }

if (choice == 5 && i ==1) {
    pickImageButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    editTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}else{
    nextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pickImageButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}

        if (i == arrayLen()) {
            showTextButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            editTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            wordTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            nextButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            wordTextView1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


        }

        enteredWords[i] = editTextView.getText().toString();



    }
```

Here is the XML for the button :

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/nextButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="180dp"
        android:onClick="nextWord"
        android:text="Next"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/enterEditText"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

Comment: Does that `Button` not look like it covers everywhere it responds to clicks? It looks like it's covering a large portion of the `Activity`, just going by the constraints, and some assumptions.

Comment: Why is the button invisible? Also please share whole xml file or screenshot of how your views look like.

Comment: I have added a picture

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the size of the button (height, width or constraint), if that does not work try re-creating the button as a div.

Comment: what do you mean "as as div"?